# Report Builder 3.0 conditionally formatted cells show in HTML but not Excel

Tags: reporting-services, format, conditional-statements, reportbuilder3.0

I have added conditional formatting for cells with scores to be red, yellow, or green based on parameters.

```
= IIF(ReportItems!UserScore.Value/ReportItems!MaxScore.Value*100 < Parameters!Yellow.Value, "#f4a0a5", IIF(ReportItems!UserScore.Value/ReportItems!MaxScore.Value*100 >= Parameters!Green.Value, "#b4eeb9", "#f4e5a9"))
```

But I found that colors were also being applied to empty cells, so I added this to the beginning:

```
IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!UserScore.Value), "Transparent",
```

Now [empty raw score columns are white in Report Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFL5u.jpg) but are still colored when I export results to Excel.

I saw that this was a known issue, solved by specifying a color, so changed the fix to

```
IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!UserScore.Value), "White",
```

But [most empty Raw score columns are colored in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa6cl.jpg)

The complete expression is:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!UserScore.Value), "White", IIF(ReportItems!UserScore.Value/ReportItems!MaxScore.Value*100 < Parameters!Yellow.Value, "#f4a0a5", IIF(ReportItems!UserScore.Value/ReportItems!MaxScore.Value*100 >= Parameters!Green.Value, "#b4eeb9", "#f4e5a9")))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `Nothing` instead of "Transparent"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck. In both xls and xlsx exports, Nothing still takes on the color of the last column with a value. :(